# StackOverflowException seems to be caused by font awesome?

Tags: c#, jquery, visual-studio-2015, angular-ui-bootstrap, font-awesome

Ok so this is a little bit weird. Let me explain the situation.
We have a website that runs in a 64 bit environnement. Everything works fine for the client's website, but when we run the website in Visual Studio, it throws a StackOverflowException.

We tried in Visual Studio 2013 and Visual Studio 2015. Same result.
We tried in Debug or Release mode, same result.
We do not have recursivity in our website.

I have found out that the line that seems to cause the problem is this :

```
<td><i class="fa fa-lock"></td>
```

If I comment every references to font awesome, the webpage works and no exception. But if I make one reference to font awesome, I have the exception.

This is what the webpage looks like.

```
@using Isaac.VTWeb.Models.SecurityConfig;
@using Isaac.VTWeb.Views.SecurityConfig;

@model IList<LocalUserModel>

<ul class="breadcrumb">
  <li class="active"><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "SecurityConfig")">@SecurityConfigResource.Configuration</a> <span class="divider">/</span></li>
</ul>

<h2>@SecurityConfigResource.ManageUsers</h2>

<div>
  <a class="btn btn-primary" href="@Url.Action("AddLocalUser", "SecurityConfig")">@SecurityConfigResource.AddUserTitle</a>
</div>
<div>
  <table class="table table-condensed table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th>@SecurityConfigResource.Username</th>
      <th>@SecurityConfigResource.FirstName</th>
      <th>@SecurityConfigResource.LastName</th>
      <th>@SecurityConfigResource.Actions</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
      <tr>
        <!--This is the line that cases the StackOverflowException. If I comment the line, everything works fine.-->
        <td><i class="fa fa-lock"></td>

        <td>@item.Username</td>
        <td>@item.FirstName</td>
        <td>@item.LastName</td>
      </tr>
    }
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

There is about 340 items in "Model" so the foreach is executed about 340 times.
We use jQuery version 1.5.5, bootstrap 1.3.2 and font awesome 4.6.3.

The exception occurs in System.Web.dll and I have no callStack when it happens.
[image]

Any ideas??

Comment: That's very weird. My guess it it has something to do with the fact that the `<i>` tag is never closed as font-awesome itself is still loaded regardless of whether you're using the css classes or not. Try changing it to `<i class="fa fa-lock" />` or `<i class="fa fa-lock"></i>`

Comment: That is exactly the problem!! Thank you so much! I've spend so much time searching and haven't noticed!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to close the `<i>` tag

```
<i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
```